# async await redux this.props.func call?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, async-await

I use connect decorator so

is there any different for these 2 blocks of code?

```
@connect(,{fetchList, fetchItem})
class MyClass extends React.Component {
   async componentDidMount() {
     await this.props.fetchList()
     await this.props.fetchItem()
   }
}
```

Block 2

```
@connect(,{fetchList, fetchItem})
class MyClass extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
     this.props.fetchList()
     this.props.fetchItem()
   }
}
```

Both worked, but does async await in block 1 make fetchItem got called after fetchList is done?

Answer (score 1):

Important point: both methods you call in cDM return `Promise` we can wait for. if it is not there is no any difference(but no errors too).

if this point is satisfied then first version runs requests sequentially and responses will be fulfilled in the same order. Second version runs requests in parallel and responses may come and be processed in any way.

We may rewrite `async-await` version without those operators(and they just have different syntax but are equal):

```
componentDidMount() {
    return Promisle.resolve(this.props.fetchList())
        .then(() => Promise.resolve(this.props.fetchItem()));
}
```

`Promise.resolve` there handles the case if call does not return `Promise`.

Want to highlight that in both cases `componentDidMount` is "just called l by React so nothing checks if it returns `Promise` or not. So for React as a platform of your components there is no difference.

Hope this makes things clear.

Comment: make sense but I want to avoid promise, why not use async await?

Comment: I wanted to illustrate how it's working under the hood. `async` forces function be returning `Promise`. any `await` inside of it just virtually wraps all code below as nested `.then(resultOfStatesmentNearAwait => {...all code below...}`. no magic, same old good `Promise` chain inside but with better syntax.

Comment: In my experience doing `await this.props.fetchList();
     await this.props.fetchItem()
 ` make fecthItem to wait for fetchList to finish.

Comment: yes, the same, as calling `fetchItem` inside of `fetchList().then(...)`